# ngbRadioGroup fails to pre-select correct choice

Tags: angular, radio-group

I have angular 8 font end, where I am trying out the radio group control posted [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/QQyl35agwv4DM8FB7DZD/), it has the following ngbRadioGroup in the template:

```
<div [(ngModel)]="model" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic">
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1"> Left (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" value="middle"> Middle
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="false"> Right
  </label>
</div>
```

In the component, I have `model = 1;`, but the first choice is not pre-selected (it should be), instead the last choice (right-most radio button) is pre-selected (as shown below), why?

[image]

After some more trials, it appears that it will pre-select/highlight whenever a radio button's [value] evaluate to be false.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to have unique 'id' and 'name' defined for the `ngbRadioGroup` `div`.